# How put an image into a div?

Tags: html, css

I want to insert an image in a div, but i have problems: the image overflows outside the div!! O.O

(sorry for my english)
thats' the code HTML

```
 <div class='immagine2'><img src='http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3822/9522792825_c68706706d_o.jpg'></div>
```

and CSS...

```
 div.immagine2 {
      position:relative;
      width:500px;
      height:410px;
      margin: 30px 30px 30px auto; 
  }

 div.immagine2 img {
      float:left;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
      margin-left:-155px;
 margin-top:-75px;
  }
```

And [here](https://thimble.webmaker.org/project/8979/edit) the link.
what's wrong?

IMPORTANT!!! : i want that image has flow left, cause i want to add text on the right!

Comment: to be expected. you haven't told the div how to handle overlow, e.g. `overflow: none`.

Comment: It's because your image is absolutely positioned and floated. set it up within a div and text-align center it.

Comment: Nothing. it doesn't work.

Comment: The css looks very hacky... and that's never good. What exactly do you want to achieve? A centralized image in the div immagine2?

Comment: absolute position + float + negative margins = mess. Just use the `position`, `left` and `top` properties.

Comment: i need that the image has float left, cause i want to add text too on the right!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? In comments below you say "the center of the div" which seems too be in opposition to what you're asking here. Maybe make upload a diagram for us?

Comment: Also, if you have the interest, you should study a little of css positioning http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Answer (score 2):

Add the `overflow: hidden` to the following id:

```
div.immagine2 {
    overflow:hidden;
    ...
}
```

This will effectively prevent any content extending beyond the div from displaying on the page. Hope it helps!!

Comment: if i add overflow hidden, the image is cut! but i dont' want this.

Comment: i want to post image at the center of the div

Comment: @AnastasiaRiabtzeva you should edit your Question to indicate that then

Comment: Try setting the property 'text-align:center' on the parent <div> tag, div.immagine2, and remove everything but the margin declarations on the inner img div.

Answer (score 1):

Just Put the image in the `div` with `text-align: center`

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <img src="....">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the background-image to your CSS (As a commentor mentioned this is ineffective if you wish to use different images ).

```
  background-image: url(../images/picture.jpg)
```

You can play around with numerous background settings in the CSS.

```
background-size: 100%;
```

If you are using px you can specify the size the image should occupy.

```
background-size: 30px 40px;
```

Comment: It's a possible workaround, however it's not effective if you want several `.immagine2` elements with different images (and several other possibilities). Also if the image is **content** on the page it should not be moved to the CSS.

Comment: @Wesley Murch That makes perfect sense. If he does want different images he cannot include the -image part in the CSS

Comment: Original Image scaling will be lost if OP don't know what the size of the image is..

Comment: @Mr_Green That's not quite true, just don't use `background-size` in that case.

Comment: @WesleyMurch but still the div will not increase the width/height automatically to adjust the image scaling. So, the overflow still exist.. (I hope you understand)

Comment: @Mr_Green If the image is absolutely positioned it will not scale to the container anyways (and will not affect the size of the container either).

Comment: I agree the answer by @user2690306 also addresses the issue and in a more effecient way based on the OPs problem. In certain situations background size may help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow: hidden`, `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` to your `.immagine2` container will prevent the image from "spilling out" of its container, but will cause clipping or scrolling depending on how you've set `overflow`.

If you just want to contain the `<img>` within its container, set `max-width: 100%`:

```
.immagine2 img { max-width: 100%; }
```

---

**Edit**

To center your image *and* keep it in your document's flow, try the following:

```
div.immagine2 {
    margin: 30px auto; 
    width: 500px;
    height: 410px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.immagine2 img {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```